# Bash script which lists all files that contain a string literal excluding packages in OS X

Tags: macos, bash, bundle, ack

Right now I'm using `ack` to list all the files in a directory which contain a string literal. This outputs not only normal files but also special files called packages or bundles which are actually directories on OS X.  That is fine except I'm piping that to another command that is expecting only true files. How do I exclude the packages and bundles but still include the files which match my search term inside those packages and bundles?

```
$ ack --literal --files-with-matches 'SearchTerm'
```

Comment: Are you reading the output line by line? If so try something like: `[ -f "$line" ] && <some command; line is file>`. -- Better yet use `find` from the beginning.

Comment: You should be able to filter them out by "file extension" on the `ack` command-line.  Can you show your code?

Comment: @cdarke I would like a generic solution. Maybe I could filter by UTI. Is there an easy way to script that?

Answer (score 1):

1. Even if you used a regex pattern to weed out files without a dot suffix, e.g. -G '*.*' , you'll end up missing those files without a suffix. In other words, I don't think you'll find a generic regex to filter files from non-files. That said...
2. Perhaps there is a naming convention to your special files called packages or bundles? In which case, use ack's -G flag to filter them out (see the point above for an  example).
3. I'm guessing there is no way to tell these packages and bundles from other files, so I think you should resort to `find . -type f -name` and pipe the files to ack -- e.g:

   `find <dir> -type f |  ack --nofilter --literal --files-with-matches 'SearchTerm'`